# Set AuthorizationFilter property of a WebPart

Tags: 2013, csom

I have set the AuthorizationFilter using the web interface, and successfully read the value.

```
  File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);
  LimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
  context.Load(wpm.WebParts,
  wps => wps.Include(
  wp => wp.WebPart.Title));
  context.ExecuteQuery();
  foreach (WebPartDefinition wpd in wpm.WebParts)
  {
      WebPart wp = wpd.WebPart;
      if (wp.Title == webPartTitle)
      {
          var properties = wp.Properties;
          context.Load(properties);
          context.ExecuteQuery();
          return properties.FieldValues;
      }
  }
```

The property values returns AuthorizationFilter=';;CN=MyGroupName,OU=SomeOu,OU=SomeOtheOu,DC=company,DC=com;;'

If I clear the AuthorizationFilter in the web interface and try to set the identical value using the following code, I get an exception "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
If I set other properties, no exception is thrown and the respective property is updated.

```
  File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);
  LimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
  context.Load(wpm.WebParts,
  wps => wps.Include(
  wp => wp.WebPart.Title));
  context.ExecuteQuery();
  foreach (WebPartDefinition wpd in wpm.WebParts)
  {
      WebPart wp = wpd.WebPart;
      if (wp.Title == webPartTitle)
      {
          wp.Properties["AuthorizationFilter"] = ";;CN=MyGroupName,OU=SomeOu,OU=SomeOtheOu,DC=company,DC=com;;";
          wpd.SaveWebPartChanges();
          context.ExecuteQuery();  // this throws an Exception
          break;
      }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem. 
The context address used did not exactly match the url containing the WebPart

so this combination throws the exception

```
string contextAddress = "http://spserver.company.com/"
string url = "http://spserver.company.com/SomeWeb/SitePages/Homepage.aspx"
```

while this combination works fine

```
string contextAddress = "http://spserver.company.com/SomeWeb/"
string url = "http://spserver.company.com/SomeWeb/SitePages/Homepage.aspx"
```